# How to add class to the body if my div has a certain class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add a class to the body if `div` has some particular class? ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a37qLv4n/))

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="pos-target" class="pos-fixed"><!-- Code --></div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
function () {
  $('#pos-target').hasClass(pos-fixed)) { $(document.body).addClass(‘pos-change’);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if( $('#pos-target').hasClass('pos-fixed') === true ) 
{
 $('body').addClass('pos-change');
}
```

Here is a https://jsfiddle.net/5p38Lb57/

Comment: @techies Brijesh is correct to wrap the code in a $(document).ready(). At any rate would you select an answer to this question? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($('#pos-target').hasClass("pos-fixed")) 
     $("body").addClass("pos-change");
});
```